# A function to execute any function with any types and numbers of parameter in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I currently have a function that accepts a vector of any type and a function as parameters. The function that is passed is timed on execution and the resulting time is returned. The function call is invoked with the passed vector, but what I'd like to do is extend the call so that any number of parameters can be passed with the function call and it can be invoked with any number of parameters. The code for the function is below and is found in a file called functions.h:

```
template<typename X, typename F>
double timer(std::vector<X> elements, F function) {
   clock_t tstart, tend;

   tstart = clock();
   function(elements);
   tend = clock();

   return ((double)tend - tstart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

The function mean just computes the mean of the given values (which are also in a vector). The main.cpp file including the call to timer is here:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include "functions.h"

int main(void) {
   std::vector<double> x;
   x.push_back(53.0);
   x.push_back(61.0);
   x.push_back(49.0);
   x.push_back(67.0);
   x.push_back(55.0);
   x.push_back(63.0);

   double time = timer(x, mean<double>);
   std::cout << time << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

I don't know how but I believe it's possibly in the call from main that needs to be changed? Maybe to something like:

```
double time = timer(mean<double(x)>);
```

Or

```
double time = timer(fakeFunction<double(x, y)>);
```

Where the timer function would be updated to something like the following:

```
template<typename F>
double timer(F function) {
   clock_t tstart, tend;

   tstart = clock();
   function();
   tend = clock();

   return ((double)tend - tstart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to bind the arguments to the callback:

```
double time = timer(std::bind(mean<double>, x));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use variadic templates:

```
template<typename F, typename ARGn...>
double timer(F function, ARGn&& ...argn) 
{
    clock_t tstart, tend;

    tstart = clock();
    function(std::forward<ARGn>(argn)...);
    tend = clock();

    return ((double)tend - tstart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```