# C++ - Template function to accept bound function as parameter and pass it to another function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In answer to a previous question ([A function to execute any function with any types and numbers of parameter in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070518/c-how-can-i-extend-this-template-function-to-accept-a-function-as-a-paramete)) I found that I can use the std::bind method to bind parameters when passing a function as another function's argument. How do I then pass it to another function? The code for the intermediate function (repeatFunction) and timer are shown below:

```
template<typename F>
double timer(F function) {
   clock_t tstart, tend;

   tstart = clock();
   function();
   tend = clock();

   return ((double)tend - tstart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

template<typename F>
std::vector<double> repeatFunction(F function) {
   std::vector<clock_t> numCalls(9);
   std::vector<double> info;

   std::generate(numCalls.begin(), numCalls.end(), [&](){ timer(function); });
   info.push_back(mean(numCalls));
   info.push_back(standardDeviation(numCalls));
   return info;
}
```

The code takes a passed function and runs it a number of times and in turn returns the time the function took to run. The function (F function) is bound from main as shown below:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include "functions.h"

int main(void) {
   std::vector<double> x;
   x.push_back(53.0);
   x.push_back(61.0);
   x.push_back(49.0);
   x.push_back(67.0);
   x.push_back(55.0);
   x.push_back(63.0);

   std::vector<double> info = repeatFunction(std::bind(mean<double>, x));

   return 0;
}
```

Do I need to somehow get the parameters and then rebind them in the repeatFunction function?

EDIT: It actually seems to be a problem with std::generate and not actually the passed function call. Any tips on how to make generate work with the passed function call would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/algorithm:63:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::generate(_FIter, _FIter, _Generator) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >; _Generator = repeatFunction(F) [with F = std::_Bind<double (*(std::vector<double>))(std::vector<double>)>]::<lambda()>]’:
functions.h:50:4:   required from ‘std::vector<double> repeatFunction(F) [with F = std::_Bind<double (*(std::vector<double>))(std::vector<double>)>]’

Comment: main.cpp:29:72:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:5083:2: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate that `std::generate` receives needs to return a value:

```
[&] { return timer(function); }
//    ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Wow, I guess I've been staring at this way too long. Thanks again for your help.